# How this code in C is working

Tags: c

I got a code in c which will do functionality of atoi function but i don't how its working

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("\n%d\n", myatoi("1998")); 
  getch();
  return(0);
}

int myatoi(const char *string)
{
  int i;
  i=0;
  while(*string)
  {
    i=(i<<3) + (i<<1) + (*string - '0');
    string++;
  }
  return(i);
}
```

In the above code is not getting incremented and always be zero then how (i<<3) + (i<<1) will effect the code?

Comment: are you sure that code is working ?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake i have updated this working code now

Answer (score 2):

`(i<<3) + (i<<1)` (for positive numbers at least) is equivalent to multiplying by 10, because `i<<3` shifts the integer by 3 bits to the left (i.e. multiplying by 8) and `i<<1` shifts the integer by 1 bit to the left (i.e. multiplying by 2).

Each time you encounter a new digit, it multiplies the current number by 10 and adds the new digit (i.e. if your current number is 199 and you encounter the digit `8`, then your new number should be 1998 = 10 * 199 + 8.

The reason for subtracting `'0'` is that if your characters are encoded in ASCII, you need to convert the ASCII codes back to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding this code, you need to understand:

- `(i<<3)`, I mean bit operators

and

- `*string`,  `string++`, I mean string manipulation and more generally operations on pointers.

You also need to know how strings are represented in C and how numbers are represented in ASCII.

Comment: (i<<3) if i remains to be zero than nothing is there to be understand .its  always comes to be zero

Comment: `i` gets changed with the third term of the addition. I hope that you know that `while` indicates a loop.

Comment: Well mouviciel my day is really going bed today